# Close application through the website

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron

I think I am missing something with the way Electron apps are built but I am using the frame-less option in my `main.js` to hide the exit button for my application and I want to implement my own in code but I can't figure out how to trigger the actual termination of the application. I am using angular2 CLI generator project that I combined with Electron.

Based on my googling, I found I need to use `const remote = require('electron').remote;` but that gives me a `index.js:4Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` error that makes no sense to me. I believe its because I'm trying to execute a node-only module on the Angular App.
I think I am missing something.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the code that you are using, especially `index.js` and the file that you're using to try and close the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was angular CLI uses commonJS and i was trying to use require which doesn't play nicely. To solve this I added the following to my index.html

```
  <script>
    const electron = require('electron');
  </script>
```

and then in my typings.d.ts I added `declare var electron: any;` so that it doesn't throw errors when I try to access electron throughout my app.

Answer (score 0):

In the *main* process, you can close the application by calling `app.quit()` where `app` is from `require('electron')`.

If you want to close the application from the *render* process you can have the exit button send an IPC message back to the *main* process by doing something like

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('exit-message', 'close');
```

This will broadcast to *main* where you can handle it appropriately, like so

```
ipcMain.on('exit-message', (event, arg) => {
  app.quit();
  // or handle the actual message if you need other functionality
})
```

Comment: When I try to use `const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');` on the render process (angular 2 app), it still gives me that `index.js:4Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` error.